# The text is not appearing next to the floated image

Tags: html, css

Sorry, i am a beginner also i'd like to understand the solution.

I want the text to be floated next to the image also i noticed that the image doesn't fully show up instead a proportion of it is underneath the header.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
p, h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  background-color: #191919;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  color: #edf9ff;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-bottom: #0fe216 3px solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top:0;
}

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #edf9ff;
}

header ul {
  margin: 0;
}

header li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

#showtime img {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;


}
.clearfix {
  overflow:auto;
}
#img1 {
  float:right;

}
#img2 {
  float:left;
}

footer {
margin-top:30px;
  background-color:#191919;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  clear:both;
}
footer p{
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Photography | Home </title>
        <link href="About.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="Home.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <div id="branding">
                <h2>PHOTOGRAPHY</h2>
            </div>
            <nav id="links">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PHOTO GALLERY</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">VIDEO GALLERY</a></li>
            </ul>
                </nav>
        </header>
        <section id="showtime">
                <div>

                    <a href="./images/Person1.jpg"><img src="./images/Person1.jpg" width="300px;" height="300px;"></a>
                    <h2>Image</h2>
                    <p>The image will always try to be unique from the odthers and we will always try to deliver the best photo in our limited time</p>
                </div>
        </section>
              
        <footer>
            <p>Note that any copyright &copy; is reserved</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your HTML code, it looks like you don't have id's set for your images. Does fixing this solve the problem?

Comment: Doesn't seem to

Comment: maybe he / she mean  `#showtime img ` if so just add  `float:left ` for that id @ModinaBegum

Comment: still the same, the text doesn't float to the right of the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `align="left"` to float an image next to some text. The section showtime needs blank space to allow for the header height overlapping it.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
p, h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  background-color: #191919;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  color: #edf9ff;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-bottom: #0fe216 3px solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top:0;
}

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #edf9ff;
}

header ul {
  margin: 0;
}

header li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
#showtime {
padding-top:60px;
}
#showtime img {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;


}
.clearfix {
  overflow:auto;
}
#img1 {
  float:right;

}
#img2 {
  float:left;
}

footer {
margin-top:30px;
  background-color:#191919;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  clear:both;
}
footer p{
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Photography | Home </title>
        <link href="About.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="Home.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <div id="branding">
                <h2>PHOTOGRAPHY</h2>
            </div>
            <nav id="links">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PHOTO GALLERY</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">VIDEO GALLERY</a></li>
            </ul>
                </nav>
        </header>
        <section id="showtime">
                <div>

                    <a href="./images/Person1.jpg"><img align="left" src="./images/Person1.jpg" width="300px;" height="300px;"></a>
                    <h2>Image</h2>
                    <p>The image will always try to be unique from the odthers and we will always try to deliver the best photo in our limited time</p>
                </div>
        </section>
              
        <footer>
            <p>Note that any copyright &copy; is reserved</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: umm.. where did you put "align: left;" to?

Comment: The **align** attribute of any <object> is not supported in HTML5. You should use CSS instead.

Answer (score 0):

Replace CSS for the header with:

```
header {
  background-color: #191919;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  color: #edf9ff;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-bottom: #0fe216 3px solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 0;
  top: 0; // Added. Is required for fixed positioning
}
```

And add the following:

```
#showtime {
  margin-top: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to css `#showtime { padding-top: 100px;}` because `position: fixed;` removes your element from relative positioning, so you need to add extra space on top,.

and add **id** to img tag `<img id="img1" src="./images/Person1.jpg" width="300px;" height="300px;">`. This is actually not the best idea. It's better to use classes.

You should do it the proper way by adding a class to img, **id** must be unique for all HTML document elements, you can't use it more than once. For example you could do:

**CSS**
`.img1 { float: left; }`

**HTML**
`<img class="img1" src="./images/Person1.jpg" width="300" height="300">`